# Are there any drawbacks to extracting css in different classes for reusability?

Tags: html, css, sass, reusability

Are there any drawbacks to extracting css in different classes for reusability?

Rewriting the same css code over and over again seems very cumbersome to me.
We design our webpages to have pre-defined margins and paddings, so the spacing of the website stays the same.

The same goes for font sizes, font families, colors, hovers, backgrounds e.g. You get the point.

We are using sass in the code samples below.

```
.text-color-light{ color: $light-color; }
.text-color-dark{ color: $dark-color; }
.text-color-main{ color: $main-color; }
.text-color-secondary{ color: $secondary-color; }
.text-color-accent{ color: $accent-color; }

.text-hover-light:hover{ color: $light-color !important; }
.text-hover-dark:hover{ color: $dark-color !important; }
.text-hover-main:hover{ color: $main-color !important; }
.text-hover-secondary:hover{ color: $secondary-color !important; }
.text-hover-accent:hover{ color: $accent-color !important; }

.bg-light{ background: $background-color-light; min-height: 1px; }
.bg-dark{ background: $background-color-dark; min-height: 1px; }
.bg-main{ background: $main-color !important; min-height: 1px; }
.bg-secondary{  background: $secondary-color; min-height: 1px; }
.bg-accent{ background: $accent-color; min-height: 1px; }

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    .xs-bg-light{ background: $background-color-light; min-height: 1px; }
    .xs-bg-dark{ background: $background-color-dark; min-height: 1px; }
    .xs-bg-main{ background: $main-color !important; min-height: 1px; }
    .xs-bg-secondary{   background: $secondary-color; min-height: 1px; }
    .xs-bg-accent{ background: $accent-color; min-height: 1px; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of opinion and StackOverflow is not for opinions. I think doing that too much reduces the flexibility of your code. If someone just wants to change one thing in one place, it will affect all of the project.

In my experience such efficient code does not work best in a ever growing and evolving project, and few projects don't evolve.

My best idea so far is to make blocks of code that can function independently, like a block for the header, one for the footer, one for a kind of box, another for another kind of box, and so on.

Reusable components rather than reusable classes seems right to me. But it's just an opinion, there is no absolute truth here.

Comment: Looking back at this answer, what do you think about frameworks like tailwindcss?